# SLDS classes on (new) base Lightning web components don't work

Tags: lightning-web-components

SLDS classes on base Lightning web components do not appear to work... unless I'm missing something?

When I view the component below, the margin *is* properly applied to the div, but *not* to the card.

Am I missing something?

Thanks very much!

**UPDATE:** Trying `slds-m-around_large` seems to add an arbitrary (and entirely incorrect) amount of margin. It also doesn't even add on the sides, only top & bottom.. not that I want on the sides in this case.

**UPDATE 2:** I witness the same (incorrect?) thing in the Web Components Playground. But that can't be the expected behavior, can it?

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-bottom_large">
        div
    </div>

    <lightning-card class="slds-m-bottom_large">
         card 1
    </lightning-card>

    <lightning-card>
        card 2
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @vignesh Can you please share where you see this documentation? In the component library under lightning-card, I see: _Use the variant or class attributes to customize the styling._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, custom elements are set to `display: inline`. By introspecting the DOM in the playground, you can also see that the `lightning-card` doesn't override the `display` property from inside using the `:host` selector. The margin and padding are not being applied because the `lightning-card` element is `display: inline`.

In order to get the margin and padding working as you expect you will need to set the `lightning-card` display CSS property to `block`. [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/2Yqjgwrmn/1/edit)

```css
lightning-card {
    display: block;
}
```